# Using fluent API to set up composite foreign key in one-to-one relation in legacy database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, composite-key, one-to-one

I'm just a beginner in EF code first model. Given two POCO classes mapped to current legacy MS SQL database. They are associated with a composite foreign key setting up one to many relation. Since it's actually one-to-one relation I'd like to have corresponding navigation properties in my POCO objects and do mapping in fluent API. Here is my example:

```
public partial class Answer
{
    //primary key
    public int id { get; set; }

    //foreign keys
    public int question { get; set; }
    public int assignedForm { get; set; }

    //simple fields
    public short state { get; set; }
    public int author { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual AssignedQuestion AssignedQuestion { get; set; }
}

 public partial class AssignedQuestion
{
    // primary keys
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int assignedForm { get; set; }

    //simple field
    public string content { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    //public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

If I wanted to do one-to-many relation I would simply uncomment "Answers" collection and have Fluent API mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssignedQuestion>()
    .HasKey(q => new { q.id, q.assignedForm });

modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.AssignedQuestion)
    .WithMany(aq=>aq.Answers)
    .HasForeignKey(a => new { a.question,a.assignedForm});
```

My goal is to go with one-to-one relation and use "Answer" property in AssignedQuestion with such Fluent API as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssignedQuestion>()
    .HasKey(q => new { q.id, q.assignedForm });

modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.AssignedQuestion)
    .WithOptional(aq => aq.Answer);
    //.HasForeignKey(a => new { a.question, a.assignedForm });
```

The problem is I can't specify exactly foreign key fields (as in previous example) and uncomment HasForeignKey call. In this case EF tries to join tables using conventional field names "AssignedQuestion_ID" and "AssignedQuestion_AssignedForm" instead of "question" and "assignedForm" in Answer table. Is there a walkaround in Fluent API other than changing field names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not one-to-one relationship so your first mapping is correct. The reason why it is one-to-many is that EF understands one-to-one only when build on PKs on both sides. If `AssignedQuestion` has PK `id` and `assignedForm` your `Answer` will need to have FK and PK on its `id` and `assignedForm` otherwise EF doesn't see it as one-to-one relation. Even if you mark your `question` and `assignedForm` with unique constaint in database (to make it one-to-one in the database) EF will still not be able to handle it as one-to-one because it doesn't support unique constraints yet (except PK).